# Search by different parameters of stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, search, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008, and in my database I have a table called `Student`, with 3 columns `name, lastname, year`.

I want to give the user the opportunity to search students from that database by different attributes. I want to write one stored procedure, which will have 3 parameters (all the columns of `Student`) which could implement search in different ways.

If I write procedure this way:

```
Create Procedure ProcSearchStudents
@name nchar(20) = NULL,
@lastname nchar(20) = NULL,
@year int = NULL,
AS

if(@lastname = NULL)
BEGIN
Select * 
from Student
where  name = @name 
and year = @year
END

if(@name = NULL)
BEGIN
Select * 
from Student
where  lastname = @lastname 
and year = @year
END

if(@year = NULL)
BEGIN
Select * 
from Student
where  name = @name 
and lastname = @lastname
END

... 
...

GO
```

I have to write `if()` statement 3!(factorial) times. So, If I have 8 attributes, it will be almost impossible to write this.

Is there any other better way to do that, or a kind of engine, which can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a simple solution:

```
select  *
from    Student
where   (@name is null or Name = @name)
        and (@lastname is null or LastName = @lastname)
        and (@year is null or Year = @year)
```

Although simple, this suffers from the problem of "parameter sniffing".  Basically, SQL Server creates a plan for the query based on the first search you run.  This can be resolved by adding a query hint that forces SQL Server to re-create the query plan for every search:

```
select  *
from    Student
where   (@name is null or Name = @name)
        and (@lastname is null or LastName = @lastname)
        and (@year is null or Year = @year)
option  (recompile)
```

If you do a lot of queries, the overhead of compiling a plan can become too high.  In that case you have to resort to dynamic SQL.  But that's the answer to a different question.